# Does ammonia gas neutralise Hcl salt of amines in dry non polar medium

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

I am trying to basify/neutralise the $\ce{HCl}$ salt of amine and other organic compounds by bubbling dry(or semi dry) ammonia gas through a column of  the salt suspended in a non polar solvent like toluene or xylene.

Since there is little to no water present, will the ammonia gas be able to react with the Hcl to form ammonium chloride?

Comment: This is simply a bad idea. Do you know how dangerous NH3 gas is? Even as a hypothetical scenario it would be contrived.

Comment: I have lot of experience working with ammonia gas, is that the reason for all the downvotes? pen and paper chemists are running the show I guess nowadays.

Comment: Well, if you wanna risk your life instead of using things that are safer and work better, it's your call.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on the type of amine or organic compound you are using.

If you have chloride of primary, secondary or tertiary amine then it is going to be difficult because they are more basic than ammonia and would not easily lose $\ce{Cl^-}$.

If you are using aniline then ammonia can easily abstract $\ce{Cl^-}$ because it is less basic than ammonia.